# Transferring hard coded menu to wordpress and applying styles

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I was working on a website in HTML, using bootstrap, and i want to transfer it to wordpress and make a custom theme and this is where i am stuck.

I made pages and menu using wordpress admin panel, and now i want to add my own styles to that menu. Here is the code:

```
<div class="navigation">
        <?php 
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'primary',
                'container' => false,
                'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav'
                )
            ); 
        ?> 
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item right-border active">
                        <div class="mask"></div>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">HOME
                            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
```

After i import all the classes i need to remove the whole UL block and just leave the menu from wordpress.

I can access UL class using 'menu-class' => 'navbar-nav', but i have no idea how to access those other classes (mask, nav-item, right-border, active, nav-link, sr-only) and how to apply that current state to just this LI block (after this one i have more of he same LI blocks repeating, but just the first one is active).

Comment: Read the documentation on the function wp_nav_menu https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Comment: You won't be able to use the wp_nav_menu() function for what you're trying to do... as far as I can tell.

Comment: Check out [WP Bootstrap Navwalker](https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker). It is really great.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i was actually able to find the answer myself. After i use wp_nav_menu() function, it will generate a menu. I will connect it with

'theme_location' => 'primary'

So it will pull all pages that i made in wordpress. After that, the only thing i need to do is open the page and go to inspect the page. In the inspector it will show all the tags that the function will generate, and all those tags have already assigned generic classes with their own settings. So i can just use one of those classes and customize them with adding my own style to them which will change how the menu looks like, and it will apply everything i wanted to do.

Here is an image as an example:

[Menu generated by wp_nav_menu() function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rb70.png)

So as you see, i can use all of those generic classes and just edit them.